# I keep having Traceback (most recent call last): error each time I run my selenium file below. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running a selenium file with the following code in python and I keep having a traceback call error. I can't tell what the problem is. Below is the error I keep having:

```
[Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Whizzy.Ellah\PycharmProjects\virtual_assistant_final_year_project\selenium_web.py", line 2, in from selenium import webdriver File "C:\anacondaF\envs\finalYrProject\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver_init_.py", line 18, in from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox # noqa File "C:\anacondaF\envs\finalYrProject\lib\site-][1]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Whizzy.Ellah\PycharmProjects\virtual_assistant_final_year_project\selenium_web.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\anacondaF\envs\finalYrProject\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\anacondaF\envs\finalYrProject\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 26, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "C:\anacondaF\envs\finalYrProject\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .remote_connection import RemoteConnection
  File "C:\anacondaF\envs\finalYrProject\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 26, in <module>
    import urllib3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import chrome

class web_driver_info():
    def __int__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\Users\\Whizzy.Ellah\\PycharmProjects\\virtual_assistant_final_year_project\\chromedriver.exe')       

    def get_info(self, query):                 
        self.query = query                     
        self.driver.get(url='https://www.wikipedia.org')          


class_instance = web_driver_info()
class_instance.get_info("Hello")
```

Comment: Aside from typo in `__int__` (should be `__init__`) it seems you don't have urllib3 package installed. It is a requirement of selenium package that you are running. It is clearly stated as "ModuleNotFoundError". Install it and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me

I tried changing the virtual environment from anaconda to python virtual environment by deactivating the anaconda virtual env that is being used by typing `conda deactivate finalYrProject`  (finalYrProject is the name of my virtual environment) through the anaconda command prompt.

Also, I had to change the base interpreter - i.e Python interpreter by clicking on the file tab in Pycharm > settings > Python interpreter > settings' icon near the already used python interpreter selected > Show All and selected from the list of Python interpreters I had. And after running the code again everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Either urllib3 is not imported or not installed.

To import, use

```
import urllib3
```

at the top of the file. To install write:

```
pip install urllib3
```

into terminal.

Comment: I had urllib3 already installed and I tried importing it as you indicated but was having the same issue

Comment: I see you are running an conda environment did you try 'conda install -c anaconda urllib3' or 'conda install -c conda-forge urllib3'

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the two reasons mentioned by `@Ankit_Gunner` in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73324686/7429447) that:

> Either urllib3 is not imported or not installed.

There can be another possibility as follows:

- *`urllib3`* or *`requests`* module is backdated and needs a update.

In that case you need to upgrade *`urllib3`* / *`requests`* module as:

- Using *`pip`*:

  ```
  pip install --upgrade requests
  ```
- Using *`pip3`*:

  ```
  pip3 install --upgrade requests
  ```